# Create node, register, then activate using email and then publish

Tags: nodes, users

I am not sure if this is a rhetorical question but I have not found an answer yet.

I am trying to build a review system.

I have a node - A and and using nodereference url widget I have node - B, which is used to write review about a specific node - A.

Now, when I in permissions set the creation of node - B by only normal users, its all good.

But, I want to engage anonymous users too. So, I was trying to implement, in steps:
1. The nodereference url to be visible (which it shows to registered users) on node - A to be visible to anonymous users too. I have tried to fake it but it doesnt work and takes to login page which I do not want.

2. Anonymous user should be able to fill up the node - B and when click submit then,
3. Take the user to registration form, fill it up and,
4. Due to sites requirement, we have email verification, so when the activation email is clicked by that anonymous user then we publish the content.

I have tried modules,
1. Create and registration
2. r403
3. Anonymous publishing etc.

But nothing seem to be what I want.

I tried achieving this with rules but no success.

Now, I am thinking of creating a custom form and than when the user verifies then use the user hooks and publish it in actual node - B.

Or if I get a new solution here?

Thanks in advance.

anyone?

Comment: For a minute I was thinking about the [Inline Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_registration) module, but looking at the issue queue it seems that it doesn't combine too well with email verification :-(

Comment: @marcvangend nah it doesnt serve my purpose, I am tying something else, and if I succeed I will post it as answer for anyone seeking solution for the same problem in future.